# Using PHP to "check" checkbox only if it's been checked

Tags: php, checkbox

I've got a checkbox on my PHP page, and when I post back to the page I only want to check the checkbox if the user has already checked it. I'm using the following line of code, but this ALWAYS checks the checkbox, even if the user didn't check it themselves. How can I do this?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" <?php if (isset($_POST['terms']) == true) echo('checked="checked"'); ?> /> I agree to the Terms as stated above.
```

Comment: Try just outputting `checked` instead of `checked='checked`'

Comment: that looks close you can just do <?php echo isset($_POST['terms'])? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> too, probably you are confusing get and post on your form action, blank is get by default - just saying..

Answer (score 0):

You need to check $_POST['terms'] value

Comment: your syntax is invalid for your array key, its a string not a constant

Comment: I'm using my iPhone to write it so apologize me I'll correct it later

Comment: Sure, I see it all the time, anyway the issue is that the OP probably doesn't have action="post" in the form, its the only way that name != name if it's checked

Comment: I think checkboxes are being sent only if they are checked but maybe something is missing

Comment: Checkboxes are sent only if they are checked, unless they are in the $_GET instead of the $_POST then they are never sent.  And thus isset will always fail, and by extension the stickyness is never kept,

Comment: But that not his case according to his question he said it's always been checked

Answer (score 0):

Set value to that input element and check that value in the php:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" value="1" 
    <?php if (isset($_POST['terms']) && $_POST['terms'] == 1) echo('checked="checked"'); ?> 
/> I agree to the Terms as stated above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are posting with the form and not using get

```
<form action="post" >
```

leaving it blank is like saying

```
<form action="get" >
```

Look at the url to see, it's the only way `isset($_POST['terms'])` is false when you have `< input name="terms" checked="checked"/>`, unless you didn't actually check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the POST array and check the value of 'term' each time.
    `print_r($_POST);`

Your statement is correctly formed, the error must lie somewhere else.